# Calculating rotation(or spin)

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas, trigonometry

Im going through W3's ref on canvas and in one example they create a red block and the following calculation to determine its x,y:

```
this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
```

[full piece](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_movement_keyboard)

What role do sin and cos play in changing the block's x,y position?

Answer (score 0):

On that example, the speed of the object is relative to the angle.
Just try removing it and you will see what happens.

instead of:

```
this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);
```

just make it:

```
this.x += this.speed;
this.y -= this.speed;
```

Your object will no longer move in the direction of the angle.
That is just a simple practical explanation.

---

But you should read more into trigonometry:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry

And the khan academy has a course:
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry

Comment: ty for your answer and follow up links, any chance you can elaborate, why use sin and cos and not just the angle and sin for one and cos for the other ?

Comment: @sroool that is something you best figure out by yourself, you need to get a clear understanding of trigonometry ... you can certainly try any other combination you like and see how the object behaves when you try to move it